# Текст выходит за предел Эллипса

Tags: html

Как сделать что бы текст который я ввожу не выходил за пределы в теге ellipse? Или же подскажите способ записывать текст строго в сам тег ellipse

```
         <ellipse cx="100" cy="10" rx="10" ry="5" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000">

         </ellipse>

         <text x="96" y="10" class="small">this stasdasdaet</text>
```

Comment: это не html это svg - в html нету таких тегов

Comment: в `svg` всё имеет абсолютное позиционирование строго по координатам и если текст выходит то переносите его тегом `tspan` то есть в них тоже пишите `x=""` `y=""`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
  this stasdasdaet
   <tspan x="50%" dy="20%" fill="red">next line</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```